# Query nested jsonb Postgres column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a `metadata` column of type `jsonb`.

I know how to check whether it contains a specific key:

```
obj = Model.create
obj.metadata = {"foo"=>"1", "bar"=>{"baz"=>{"qux"=>2}}}
obj.save

Model.where("(metadata->'bar') IS NOT NULL") # returns obj
```

I wonder, how would I check if there is `baz` key in `obj.metadata['bar']` and, if I had, for deeper nested keys?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ok, just found a way:

```
Model.where("(metadata -> 'bar' ->> 'baz') IS NOT NULL")
```

if metadata has more nested json:

```
obj.metadata = {"foo"=>"1", "bar"=>{"baz"=>{"qux"=>2}}}
```

and I would want to see, if `there's metadata['bar']['baz']['qux']`:

```
Model.where("(metadata -> 'bar' -> 'baz' ->> 'qux') IS NOT NULL")
```